# POST request trying to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to perform a `POST` request when a link is clicked. The action keeps trying to redirect to the `POST` url.

**route**

```
post '/foo/:id/bar' => 'foo#bar', :as => 'bar'
```

**link**

```
<%= link_to 'Bar', bar_path(item), :method => :post %>
```

**action**

```
def bar
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    # Do stuff with item

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :nothing => true, :status => 200 }
    end
end
```

I've tried `format.all` and `render :nothing => true` outside of the `respond_to` statement. Stumped on why this is trying to redirect.

Comment: Are you using ajax with this action?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the same route defined earlier in your routes file probably as `resource :bar` or something similar.

Try with the route defined at the top of the file to see if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying to submit with Ajax or want the page to render something, so I've posted two examples. The regular post will return the text 'it worked!'. The ajax post will trigger a Javascript alert.

**View**

```
# app/views/foos/index.html.erb

<h1>Foos</h1>

<p><%= link_to 'Bar', '/foo/1/bar', method: :post %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Bar with ajax', '/foo/1/bar', method: :post, remote: true %></p>
```

**Controller**

```
# app/views/foos_controller.rb

class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render text: 'it worked!' }
      format.js { 
        # head :no_content
        render text: "alert('it worked!')" 
      }
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
# config/routes.rb

Testing::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/foo' => 'foos#index'
  post '/foo/:id/bar' => 'foos#bar', as: :bar
end
```

If you don't want the Javascript alert message and don't want the ajax request to return anything, uncomment `head :no_content` and remove the line `render text: "alert('it worked!')"`